# How can I run a linear regression model over two years?

Tags: regression

This might be a relatively simple question but I have not taken a course in econometrics in awhile and currently do not have access to my handy textbook that will explain.

For example, I am trying to run a regression with NBA game attendance as my dependent variable, and ticket prices, all stars (amount of all-stars on team), unemployment rate (city's UR), as well as a few other variables are my explanatory variables. The data I have available is from 2008 and 2009.

How can I use a simple linear regression model to analyze the attendance between these two years (basically, do I need to use a linear regression model or some sort of pooled model? The main thing I am trying to get at is how the crisis affected attendance)? Or am I forced to do a single regression for 2008, and then another one for 2009?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary regression assumes (among other things) that you have independent observations. When dealing with time series this is usually not the case. Review http://autobox.com/dave/regvsbox.pdf for a discussion/contrast between regression and multi-variate Box-Jenkins . What is the frequency of your observations ?